# Offloading unstructured data saved in RDBMS to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

My organization is thinking about offloading the unstructured data like Text , images etc saved as part of Tables in Oracle Database , into Hadoop. The size of the DB is around 10 TB and growing. The size of the CLOB/BLOB columns is around 3 TB.Right now these columns are queried for certain kind of reports through a web application. They are also written into but not very frequently.

What kind of approach we can take to achieve proper offloading of data and ensuring that the offloaded data is available for read through existing web application.

Comment: Querying HDFS shouldn't be done from a web application. Use HBase or Cassandra instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get part of the answer in oracle blog ([link](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/data-loading-into-hdfs-part2-data-movement-from-the-oracle-database-to-the-hdfs)).

If data needs to be pulled in HDFS environment via sqoop, then you must first read the following from sqoop documentation.

*Sqoop handles large objects (BLOB and CLOB columns) in particular ways. If this data is truly large, then these columns should not be fully materialized in memory for manipulation, as most columns are. Instead, their data is handled in a streaming fashion. Large objects can be stored inline with the rest of the data, in which case they are fully materialized in memory on every access, or they can be stored in a secondary storage file linked to the primary data storage. By default, large objects less than 16 MB in size are stored inline with the rest of the data. At a larger size, they are stored in files in the _lobs subdirectory of the import target directory. These files are stored in a separate format optimized for large record storage, which can accomodate records of up to 2^63 bytes each. The size at which lobs spill into separate files is controlled by the --inline-lob-limit argument, which takes a parameter specifying the largest lob size to keep inline, in bytes. If you set the inline LOB limit to 0, all large objects will be placed in external storage.*

Reading via web application is possible if you are using MPP query engine like Impala and it works pretty well and it is production ready technology. We heavily use complex Impala queries to render content for SpringBoot application. Since Impala runs everything in memory, there is a chance of slowness or failure if it is multi-tenant Cloudera cluster. For smaller user groups (1000-2000 user base) it works perfectly fine.

Do let me know if you need more input.

Recommendation will be

1. Use Cloudera distribution ([read here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/impala_intro.html))
2. Give enough memory for Impala Deamons
3. Make sure you YARN is configured correctly for schedule (fair share or priority share) based ETL load vs Web Application Load
4. If required keep the Impala Daemons away from YARN
5. Define memory quota for Impala Memory so it allows concurrent queries
6. Flatten your queries so Impala runs faster without joins and shuffles.
7. If you are reading just a few columns, store in Parquet, it works very fast.